# Is there a way to add private attributes to MPD without violating the DASH standard?

Tags: live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I want to add a private attribute "programDateTime" to MPD, just like this:
<MPD type="dynamic" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" **programDateTime**="2023-06-09T07:57:40Z"...>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MPD type="dynamic" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" maxSegmentDuration="PT12.000S" minBufferTime="PT9.000S" minimumUpdatePeriod="PT6.000S" suggestedPresentationDelay="PT4.000S" timeShiftBufferDepth="PT12H" availabilityStartTime="1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" publishTime="2023-06-09T08:02:15Z" programDateTime="2023-06-09T07:57:40Z" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd">
    <Period id="0" start="PT468415H57M40.000S">
        <AdaptationSet id="0" contentType="video" mimeType="video/mp4" minBandwidth="412000" maxBandwidth="3000000" minWidth="512" maxWidth="1920" minHeight="288" maxHeight="1080" minFrameRate="25000/1000" maxFrameRate="25000/1000" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
            <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="main" />
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000000" presentationTimeOffset="1686297460000000" duration="6000000" startNumber="281049576" media="$RepresentationID$/$RepresentationID$-$Number$.mp4" initialization="$RepresentationID$/$RepresentationID$-init.mp4" />
            <Representation width="1920" height="1080" frameRate="25000/1000" sar="1:1" codecs="avc1.4D4028" id="test_3000_video" bandwidth="3000000" />
            <Representation width="896" height="504" frameRate="25000/1000" sar="1:1" codecs="avc1.4D401F" id="test_1640_video" bandwidth="1640000" />
            <Representation width="896" height="504" frameRate="25000/1000" sar="1:1" codecs="avc1.4D401F" id="test_1100_video" bandwidth="1100000" />
            <Representation width="640" height="360" frameRate="25000/1000" sar="1:1" codecs="avc1.4D401E" id="test_728_video" bandwidth="728000" />
            <Representation width="512" height="288" frameRate="25000/1000" sar="1:1" codecs="avc1.4D4015" id="test_412_video" bandwidth="412000" />
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
    <UTCTiming schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:utc:direct:2014" value="2023-06-09T08:02:16.000000Z" />
</MPD>
```

The MPD with the private attribute cannot pass the [DASH validator](https://conformance.dashif.org/) and it report error:"

✗ MPD validation failed
✗ Schematron validation failed".

Is there a way to add private attributes to MPD without violating the DASH standard and make it pass the Dash validator?

Thanks in advance!